# Не отображается логотип android приложения при свёрнутом виде

Tags: android

Как исправить ? При сворачивании приложений не показывается логотип.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы используете Debug версию. По идеи на Release все будет нормально. Или вы не правильно заместили стандартные иконки, посмотрите все ли размерности вы заменили на соответствующие.

Иконки находятся по пути res/mipmap там должно быть две папки, одна для квадратной иконки, вторая для круглой. Не забудьте в манифесте приложения указать `android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"` (для круглых)         `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` (для квадратных)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ